# After enabling proguard null pointer exception

Tags: android, proguard

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ‘boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)’ on a null object reference

After debugging I have come to the conclusion that this is because that a value is not being passed from one activity to the other using putextra. This error only happens after enabling proguard. I am not aware of any keep rules to prevent this.

Currently my proguard file looks like this:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep class * extends com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule {
 <init>(...);
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}
-keep class com.bumptech.glide.load.data.ParcelFileDescriptorRewinder$InternalRewinder {
  *** rewind();
}

-keep public class pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifIOException{<init>(int, java.lang.String);}



-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.* { *;}
-dontwarn okio.


-dontshrink
-dontoptimize

# unknown stuff



-android
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-keepattributes *Annotation*


-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider

-keep public class * extends android.view.View {
    public <init>(android.content.Context);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
    public void set*(...);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * extends android.content.Context {
   public void *(android.view.View);
   public void *(android.view.MenuItem);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
    static ** CREATOR;
}

-keepclassmembers class **.R$* {
    public static <fields>;
}

-keepclassmembers class * {
    @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface <methods>;
}
```

I don't understand proguard much. I have added rules as required by third party libraries. Other than that I use firebase and some classes with getter and setter methods. Activity has all its members as private. It is my understanding that there is a null pointer exception occurring due to inability to pass values between intents using putextra after enabling proguard and so the value of variable of the second activity remains null.

How to solve this and better write proguard rules?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should give more details.
For example, you have a folder named model and inside you have a response model class.

**Your FileTree**

```
-model
--Response.java
```

If you do not specify this in proguard, the release app will not be able to use it as a reference, because proguard will change keys on memory. so you should remove your models from proguard. And finally, the app cannot wrong reference key on memory, after then you will get a null pointer error.

```
-keep class com.name.app.model.** { *; }
```

Thus, the model folder will not interfere with its classes within